# Xscreensaver Debian 11 not functioning properly on LXQt

Tags: screen-lock, xscreensaver

Hi I am running Debian 11 Bullseye, LXQt version, and I'm having trouble with the screensaver called `XScreensaver` version 5.45.

- Basically what I would like to do is for the screen to completely shut off when I'm not using the computer for 10 minutes and for there to be a screen lock so when I or anyone else tries to go into the computer they need to type in my computer password.
- However currently when I'm using this screensaver it's going to a blank screen which is a black screen but it is still giving some brightness so if I'm sleeping I will see this brightness. I want my screen to completely turned off, but to have the computer and some apps like FTP program `gftp`, transmission QT BitTorrent, or Firefox browser and of course the internet to be running.
- Also, when I'm watching a movie/video or playing music, the `xscreensaver` activates and I have to put in my password every 10 minutes or so. Even if I change the settings temporarily and I put 720 minutes or something or even completely disable the screensaver, it still activates and I have to put in my password. I don't want the xscreensaver to activate at all when any audio or video application window is maximized. Only when the windows are minimized. I use VLC media player, Audacious, DeadBeef, and other audio and video players as well.

I'm a newbie at this operating system, so how would I do this? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem using xscreensaver on Debian 12/bookworm (sid) with XFCE. My recommendations here are basically the result of playing around with various setting options.

---

Regarding bullet 3, `xscreensaver` activating every ~10 minutes even after changing settings - this may be because you haven't restarted `xscreensaver` after changing the settings. Make the changes to the timeout duration, and then from the settings window do either File -> Restart Daemon or File -> Kill Daemon and start `xscreeensaver` again manually. If you want to blank the screen after 10 minutes but not lock until some time after blanking, change the time setting for Lock Screen After (time) minutes at the bottom. To completely turn off locking, uncheck the box by Lock Screen After.

From reading the documentation in `man xscreensaver`, there does not appear to be a way within the `xscreensaver-settings` to blank without locking when you are playing media but not interacting with the computer while also blanking and locking when you are *not* playing media but still not interacting with the computer. My recommendation would be to turn off time-based locking in `xscreensaver` and write your own script to (1) watch for lack of keyboard/mouse inputs for some amount of time (indicating not using the computer) and (2) watch for the screensaver to activate (indicating that media is not playing). If both are met, then call `xscreensaver-command --lock` to lock the computer.

I have not had to deal with screensaver activating while using audio or video applications, but the documentation in `man xscreensaver` says

> **PLAYING VIDEOS**
>
> Likewise, if you have **systemd**(1) 221 or newer, or **elogind**(8), then all of the popular video players and web browsers will prevent XScreenSaver from blanking the screen while the video is playing.
>
> Both of these features require that **xscreensaver-systemd**(6) be able connect to the systemd bus. Parts of KDE and GNOME may need to be disabled first for that to work; see below.

Thus, I recommend you look into whether xscreensaver-systemd can connect to the bus. As I said, this is not an issue for me, so I haven't looked into it and don't know how to resolve this part of your question. I am not sure if the maximized/minimized status will affect the activation of the screensaver through this.

---

Regarding bullet 2, blank screen with brightness - I believe the standard "blank screen" causes the screen to display (or attempting to display) black, but this is still bright because the panels are backlit to display any colors, including black. To turn the monitor *off*, open `xscreensaver-settings`, switch to the Advanced tab, and under Display Power Management (on right hand side) check the box for Quick Power-off in Blank Only Mode. This will completely cut power to the monitor when the screensaver activates. You should not need to check Power Management Enabled or set any of the other settings within that section *unless* your screensaver display mode is set to something other than Blank Screen Only (not extensively tested, no guarantees).

When the screen blanks, either by power off or displaying black, your applications should continue to run. If they do not, then you may have your system power settings configured to suspend/sleep/hibernate/log off after the same time as the screensaver or lock, or to suspend/whatever when the screensaver/lock is activated.